# $rootScope:inprog $apply already in progress .change event error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my project, I'm trying to upload an image, read it as a dataURL and store it into my database.

my HTML ng-click's call these methods with either true or false as a parameter (one does body image and the other a profile image)

Depending on whether true or false is called, it changes the id's for the event.

For some reason, when its "true" everything works perfectly fine.  The user can pick the image, it gets sent to the database properly, and the image is loaded properly.

However, when "false" is called, I get the error:

> **[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress**

and then the console.log() test **"2222"** does not get called.

Html

```
<img src="{{controller.myCause.causeImage}}" ng-click="controller.uploadImage('true')" alt="Your Image Here" class="cause-img" id="profileImage" style="width: 80%; height: 35%;" height="300" />
<input id="imageUpload" type='file'>

<img src="{{controller.myCause.causeThumbnailImage}}" ng-click="controller.uploadImage('false')" alt="Your Thumbnail Here" id="profileImageThumb" class="cause-img" style="width: 80%; height: 20%;" height="200" />
<input id="profileImageUpload" type='file'>
```

Client Side

```js
/////////////////////////////////////
//Begin Uploading Cause Profile Image
public uploadImage(bool) {
    if (bool === "true") {
        $("#imageUpload").click();
        this.imgUpload(bool);
    } else {
        $("#profileImageThumb").click();
        this.imgUpload(bool);
    }
}

public imgUpload(bool) {
    console.log(bool);
    var _this = this;
    var id = "";
    var imgId = "";

    if (bool === "true") {
        id = "#imageUpload";
        imgId = "#profileImage";
    } else {
        id = "#profileImageUpload";
        imgId = "#profileImageThumb";
    }

    console.log("111");

    $(id).change(function () {
        console.log("2222");
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            $(imgId).attr('src', this.files[0]);
            _this.convertFileToBase64AndSet(this.files, bool);
        }  
    });

};

convertFileToBase64AndSet(fileList: FileList, bool) {
    var self = this;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = (e: Event) => {
            self.postProfileImage(reader.result, bool);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
    }
}

public postProfileImage(file, bool) {

    if (bool === "true") {
        this.$http.put(`api/causes/profpic`, JSON.stringify(file)).then((res) => {
            this.$state.reload();
        });
    } else {
        this.$http.put(`api/causes/thumbpic`, JSON.stringify(file)).then((res) => {
            this.$state.reload();
        });
    }
}
//End Cause Profile Image Upload
////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle here

Comment: do you call $apply somewhere

Comment: I do not call $apply anywhere.

Comment: The problem is arising from your angular code triggering a `.click()` on an element, which in turn triggers a digest. avoid putting DOM manipulation in your controller.

Comment: @WilliamB Thank you, do you have any suggestion on how to fix my issue besides that?

Comment: I have solved a question which is almost same with yours and I updated my old answer:)

Comment: added an answer based on @hasan response and setTimeout method

Comment: @AlexLiosatos did it work?

Comment: Yes, it did, thanks.  Already submitted urs as an answer and up arrowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @hasan's answer, I got to this one.

```
public uploadImage(bool) {
    var self = this;
    var id = "";
    if (bool === "true") {
        id = "#imageUpload";
    } else {
        id = "#profileImageUpload";
    }
    setTimeout( () => {
        $(id).click();
        self.imgUpload(bool);
    });
}
```

Thank you Hasan for pointing me in the right direction.  setTimeout does indeed work!

Comment: it might resolve the problem but we still do not know the rootcause, also this approach is smelly. Guys, if u ever have digest cycle conflicts, do not just simply wrap up your code with a bunch of timeouts!

Answer (score 1):

Your click event is running digest cycle which is conflicting with current digest cycle.

you can use `setTimeout()`

Can you try this

```
public uploadImage(bool) {
    if (bool === "true") {
        setTimeout(function({$("#imageUpload").click();})            
        this.imgUpload(bool);
    } else {            
        setTimeout(function({$("#profileImageThumb").click();})
        this.imgUpload(bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: $scope is not recognized when I try to enter it.

Comment: you should add  $scope service in your controller function($scope)

Comment: I tried pasting this into my file and there's a bunch of errors, probably has to do with the locations of the braces or parenthesis, even rewriting it doesn't work.